# Woman giving away husbands money

Tags: women, marriage, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, transactions, masechet-moed-katan

The gemorah in [Moed Katan Daf 8a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=12&daf=8&format=text) says,

> אמר רב כהנא אמר רב יהודה אמר רב מעשה באדם אחד שכינס מעות לעלות לרגל
> ובא ספדן ועמד על פתח ביתו ונטלתן אשתו ונתנתן לו ונמנע ולא עלה
>
> Rav Kahana said in the name of Rav Yehudah in the name of Rav: It once happened that a certain person had saved up money to go up [to Jerusalem] for the holiday (Pesach, Shavuos, or Sukos); and a eulogizer came and stood by the entrance to his house, and [the certain person]'s wife took [the money] and gave it to [the eulogizer], and [the certain person] was prevented from going up [to Jerusalem].

Although perhaps this is only a "kasha on a maaseh," how could his wife take the money from her husband and give it? It's technically not her money to give. Do we have to assume she gave it with his reshus (authority)? Why does the gemorah davka (specifically) describe his wife giving the money?

Comment: It's what happened, doesn't seem to be the point. The money could have been burnt or lost as well.

Comment: In terms of the gemorah there this point is not relevant. Like I said somewhat of a kasha on a maaseh...But still a question...

Answer (score 5):

Interesting question! While we can only guess as to what exactly happened, we do find a concept in a number of places (see for example Choshen Mishpat siman 62) of a woman who is נושאת ונותנת בתוך הבית, which means that she runs the household, and thus may use her husband's money to purchase things, to hire workers, etc. Perhaps she had this status, and thus was allowed to pay the eulogizer.